# Is the following identity correct? $e^1 = \int_0^1 (1 + nx^n) e^{x^n} dx\, , \forall n$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to solve the following definite integral

$$
\int_0^1 e^{x^n}\,dx\, ,
$$

for the limit in which $n\rightarrow\infty$. I proceeded by carrying out integration by parts:

$$
\int_0^1 e^{x^n}\,dx =  xe^{x^n} \bigg\rvert^1_0 - \int^1_0 nx^ne^{x^n}\,dx\\
\Rightarrow e^1 = \int_0^1 (1+nx^n) e^{x^n}\,dx, \forall n
$$

I was surprised that my working seemed to show that this was true for all values of $n$. Is there any mistake made in the derivation of this identity?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int \big[f(x)+xf'(x)\big]dx = xf(x)$$
where $f(x)=e^{x^n}$

So that $$\int (1 + nx^n) e^{x^n} dx=e^{x^n}\,, \forall n$$
which can be calculated according to any limits.

So, what you've done is correct for all $n$!